# Jquery Scrolltop - undentified top

Tags: jquery, scrolltop

I've got a question about scollTop. I've looked at other topics here, but that doesn't fix my problem.

This is the code i'm using:

```
var id = location.search.replace('?').split('=');

$('html,body').animate({
  scrollTop: $("#"+id[1]).offset().top
},
'slow');
```

But i got a console error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined.

But i really don't know what i'm doing wrong, because the var id is working correctly, even when i change 'html,body' to #container it doesn't change a thing.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you get as an `id`? Can you share some more code (HTML). And what does your id look like?

Comment: Offcourse i'm sorry. I get the ID from the url http://mywebsite.com/index.php?id=50. So var id is only a number. Thats why i have to add a "#" in the animate function.

The div looks like this:

<div id="blog-50 class="blog-item">

</div>

Oh i forget to add "#blog-" in the example.

Answer (score 0):

error happens because object

```
$("#"+id[1])
```

is not found